# How do I accelerate the touchesBegan event firing?

Tags: performance, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, event-handling, touch

I have a UIView where I use the touchesbegan event, but I realized that once I put my finger on it, the touchesBegan event takes like 1 or 2 seconds to fire. How can I make this happen faster?

thanks!!!

Comment: well, clearly you're doing something wrong, but it's hard to guess what.  more information needed--how are you measuring the delay?  is the delay different if you move your finger around vs. touching and leaving it there?  could another view be eating the events?

Comment: I´m not measuring the delay in a "mathematical" way...I just notice the strange delay when using the app in a real device. I managed to fix some memory management bugs and its seems to have fix the delay bug.But for the sake of knowladge, is there a way of knowing if the response chain is to long? or if another view might be eating the event? without having to infect my code with NSlogs every where?

Answer (score -1):

After trying some stuff out, I realized that the delay happens only on custom UIButtons. If I  "simulate" a button with a regular UIView subclass I get the correct behaviour.